# Change gradient colors in Inkscape

Tags: color, inkscape, gradient

How can I change the color from which to which the gradient should be changing in Inkscape?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image]

With the gradient tool selected (Ctrl+F1) select the start/end of the gradient and choose a desired color from the palette or the Fill&Stroke dialogue.
Double clicking on the gradient (blue line) adds a stop, which you then can also select and choose a color for.

Comment: Double clicking does not work. Look at the question. I updated it.

Comment: in the screen shot you have the "path tool" selected. Make sure you select the gradient tool ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Another approach is, when the gradient tool is selected and your blue line visible, to click on the starting point, the small circle, and select a color, and into the endpoint, the square, and select a second color.

When those marks are selected, they turn solid, to indicate selection.

A third way to do it: Select the area with gradient and then select the color dialog, the brush icon in the toolbar, "Filling and Contur". The current gradient should show up. Then hit the small pen symbol in the bottom part of the dialog "edit gradient". In the tool config bar, a combobox should appear "Stopps" with your colors. You can select one of them and change it in the color dialog. Then select the other one to do the same.

Comment: Oh, so both my tool and selection changes when I click Edit... now I get it. I found it very confusing when it looked like my selected object changed from gradient to solid color without any visible effect.