# How to change Inkscape gradient colors?

Tags: inkscape, gradient

I created a gradient in Inkscape, but now no matter where I click, I can't change the colors of the existing gradient. I did check out [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100479/change-gradient-colors-in-inkscape), but it was totally unhelpful and the "documentation" [here](http://write.flossmanuals.net/start-with-inkscape/creating-gradients/) was not the UI I could summon from any logical place.

Here's a picture of what I see, I can only change the name here, very annoying:

[image: image of annoying Inkscape UI]

When I try to change it from the bottom bar, either it switches to a constant fill, I can unset the fill/stroke but there's nothing else:

[image: another image of annoying Inkscape UI]

What's the weird place I should be looking at to find a way to change both of the gradient's colors?

Answer (score 4):

In Inkscape 1.0, when you select the gradient (as in your 1st picture), then you can check the edit icon below (or alternatively, use the gradient editing tool by pressing G).

A guide with 2 nodes appears on your figure (in the canvas). You can select each node and change its colour, or you can double click in between and add more nodes.